# dtreevizをインポートする際にエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, dtreeviz

以下のコードでdtreeviz をインポートしたいのですが、

```
from dtreeviz.trees import dtreeviz
```

実行すると、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
cannot import name 'dtreeviz' from 'dtreeviz.trees'
```

Graphvizはインストール済み、パスは設定しています。

Windows 11 を使用しています。

Comment: `from dtreeviz import dtreeviz` としてみて下さい。

Comment: 質問には[dtreeviz 2.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/dtreeviz/)自身をインストールしたとは書かれていませんが書き忘れでしょうか？ それからAnaconda系かどうかが重要な条件かもしれません。[dtreevizをインストールして決定木を可視化する【Python】](https://self-development.info/dtreeviz%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%B1%BA%E5%AE%9A%E6%9C%A8%E3%82%92%E5%8F%AF%E8%A6%96%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%90python%E3%80%91/), [決定木の可視化ライブラリ dtreeviz を conda でインストールする](https://analytics-note.xyz/machine-learning/dtreeviz-conda-install/), [決定木の可視化ライブラリdtreevizのインストール](https://qiita.com/taungyeon/items/87c7faee18a800c8368a)

Comment: あとありがちなのが、テストしようとしているスクリプトのファイル名が`dtreeviz.py`とかカレントディレクトリやサーチパスの何処かにその名前の別のスクリプトが存在する等ですね。

Comment: from dtreeviz import dtreeviz　で解決しました

Answer (score 3):

後に行われた質問の方で併せて回答しましたがあらためて、[dtreevizの改版](https://pypi.org/project/dtreeviz/#history) により仕様が変わったものと思われます。
[Releases / 2.0.0](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/releases/tag/2.0.0) に新旧の記述が有り、新しいAPIでは`from`を使わない単独の`import`だけにするのが推奨のようですね。

```
import dtreeviz
```

なるべく互換性を保つために以下の方法も記載されているようですが、最新版に合わせるなら上記を使う方が良いでしょう。

```
from dtreeviz import *
```