# 決定木描画でエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3, dtreeviz

決定木を描画するために以下のコードを実行。

```
# indexの抽出
x_0 = df_info.resample('M').count()
x_0 = x_0.drop(x_0.columns.values,axis=1)
time_index = x_0.index
print(time_index)

#決定木を描画
viz = dtreeviz(
    clf,
    data_e, 
    data_o,
    target_name='Class',
    feature_names=time_index,
    class_names=['False','True'],
) 
viz
```

以下のTypeError が出ます。

```
C:\Users\ichir\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10292\1620574054.py:10: DeprecationWarning: dtreeviz() function is deprecated starting from version 2.0. 
 For the same functionality, please use this code instead: 
 m = dtreeviz.model(...) 
 m.view()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 10
      7 print(time_index)
      9 # 決定木を描画
---> 10 viz = dtreeviz(
     11     clf,
     12     data_e, 
     13     data_o,
     14     target_name='Class',
     15     feature_names=time_index,
     16     class_names=['False','True']
     17 ) 
     18 viz

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\compatibility.py:254, in dtreeviz(tree_model, X_train, y_train, feature_names, target_name, class_names, tree_index, precision, orientation, instance_orientation, show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, highlight_path, X, max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize, fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)
    251 shadow_tree = ShadowDecTree.get_shadow_tree(tree_model, X_train, y_train, feature_names, target_name, class_names,
    252                                             tree_index)
    253 model = DTreeVizAPI(shadow_tree)
--> 254 return model.view(precision, orientation,
    255                   instance_orientation,
    256                   show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, highlight_path, X,
    257                   max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize,
    258                   fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\trees.py:454, in DTreeVizAPI.view(self, precision, orientation, instance_orientation, show_root_edge_labels, show_node_labels, show_just_path, fancy, histtype, leaftype, highlight_path, x, max_X_features_LR, max_X_features_TD, depth_range_to_display, label_fontsize, ticks_fontsize, fontname, title, title_fontsize, colors, scale)
    451         return self.shadow_tree.leaves
    453 n_classes = self.shadow_tree.nclasses()
--> 454 colors = adjust_colors(colors, n_classes)
    456 if orientation == "TD":
    457     ranksep = ".2"

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtreeviz\colors.py:119, in adjust_colors(colors, n_classes, cmp)
    116         COLORS["classes"] = get_hex_colors(n_classes, cmp)
    117     return COLORS
--> 119 return dict(COLORS, **colors)

TypeError: dict() argument after ** must be a mapping, not float
```

以下各変数になります。

```
x_0.head(5)

日時
2018-11-30
2018-12-31
2019-01-31
2019-02-28
2019-03-31


df_info.head(5)
    顧客ID    宿泊者名    プラン 金額
日時              
2018-11-01 00:02:21 110034  若松 花子   B   19000
2018-11-01 00:03:10 112804  津田 美加子  D   20000
2018-11-01 00:06:19 110275  吉本 美加子  D   20000
2018-11-01 00:08:41 110169  坂本 直人   B   19000
2018-11-01 00:12:22 111504  青山 零    A   15000
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [ひとつ前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/93612/3060) は解決済みということでしょうか？もしそうであればほったらかしにせず、コメントに対して返信を行うか、ご自身で回答を投稿してください。

Comment: 「TypeError:　dict() argument after ** must be a mapping, not float」の発生元はどこでしょうか？出来るだけエラーメッセージ全文を載せましょう。

Comment: おそらくJupyter Notebook/Lab等で該当のセルだけ提示されているのだと思われますが、importや何処に有るデータをどう読み込んだか等の準備も含めて推測や補完の必要が無い完結したプログラムおよび使用するデータを提示するようにしてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

前回の質問もそうですが、[dtreevizの改版](https://pypi.org/project/dtreeviz/#history) により仕様が変わったものと思われます。

例えばこれらの記事のプログラムですが、1.4.1版まではそのまま動作しますが、2.0.0版以後では前回および今回の質問のようなエラーが発生します。
[dtreevizをインストールして決定木を可視化する【Python】](https://self-development.info/dtreeviz%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%B1%BA%E5%AE%9A%E6%9C%A8%E3%82%92%E5%8F%AF%E8%A6%96%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%90python%E3%80%91/)
[Pythonライブラリ(決定木の可視化)：dtreeviz](https://note.com/kiyo_ai_note/n/n0df3f4d33139)

変更された仕様を調べてそれに合うようにプログラムを修正するか、以下のようにdtreevizをインストールする際に動作する版数を指定して試してみてはどうでしょう？
Jupyterのセル上でのインストール例：

```
!pip install -U dtreeviz==1.4.1
```

---

2.0.0版以後はどうなったのかという情報は以下のリリース時の情報に記述があるようです。
[Releases / 2.0.0](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/releases/tag/2.0.0)

それに沿って最新版へ対応するようにプログラムを修正するとしたら以下のようになるのでは？

importは以下の形にする：

```
import dtreeviz
```

メソッドの呼び出しは(実は既にエラーメッセージの冒頭に書かれていますが)以下のようにする：

```
viz = dtreeviz.model( #### 以下省略
```

Answer (score 0):

以下のように変えた結果、実行できました。

```
import dtreeviz

# indexの抽出
x_0 = df_info.resample('M').count()
x_0 = x_0.drop(x_0.columns.values,axis=1)
time_index = x_0.index
print(time_index)

# 決定木を描画
viz = dtreeviz.model(
    clf,
    data_e, 
    data_o,
    target_name='Class',
    feature_names=time_index,
    class_names=['False','True']
) 
viz.view()
```

dtreeevizのバージョンは調べたところ1.4.0 です。
conda環境なので、それが関係あるかどうか不明です。

Comment: 前回質問のコメントにも書きましたが、環境や版数の違いは場合によっては影響があるので、なるべく質問にはあらかじめ情報を詳しく書いてください。それらが書かれていると素早い助言・回答が得られる可能性も高まります。